# Major problem with 100% height div

Tags: css, height

[image]

```
/* Left menu */
.leftMenu{
    width: 200px;
    border:2px solid green;
    float:left;
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
}

/* Main Content area */
.mainBox{
    border:2px solid red;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.mainWrapper{
    border:2px solid white;
}
```

With

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="leftMenu">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="mainBox">
        main<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>        
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How the blazes do I get the left menu to extend to the bottom?

Please note I've tried faux columns but they just don't work as the white main box just is at the front for some reason.

Comment: Would it be alright to have to specify a `min-height` for the left column?

Comment: Yes but this doesn't fill the height

Comment: I have an idea for a solution which would work in at least IE7+, so long as you can specify a `min-height` on the left column. Does that sound acceptable?

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be backwards compatible to IE6, nothing I can do about that I'm affraid :-(

Comment: I will spend the time to actually see if my idea works, and if I can make it IE6 friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/PH3t2/

I've added `postion:absolute` , `top:0` and `bottom:0` to your leftmenu

I've given mainBox `padding-left: 205px`

I've given mainWrapper `position:relative`

Feel free to add content to mainBox to see that leftMenu grows as well.

---

To finish this off and make it [work in IE6](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/), add:

```
.leftMenu, .mainBox {
    min-height: 250px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding more content to the left column. This is pretty much the solution I was thinking of, but it's missing the finishing touches (such as `min-height`, and how to make it work in IE6).

Comment: Ah good that my answer works out for you Tom. :) I don't work much with IE6 so didn't realise how to make it work for that browser. Thanks for the additional CSS thirtydot

Answer (score 3):

you need set a fixed height for the `.mainWrapper` for example `100px`; and then you set the height of `.leftMenu` to `100%;`

**Edit:** According your comment, I am not sure if it possible with pure css. If it's acceptable a javascript solution then you can use jquery and the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.leftMenu').css("height",$('.mainWrapper').height());
});
```

*Live example:* http://jsbin.com/udowu4/2

Comment: Mainwrapper expands with the content within it, it is of no fixed height

Comment: Thanks for a solution I'd rather have it in pure CSS though.  It seems ridiculous that CSS doesn't have a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

CSS Faux columns is the best possible solution. The following solution might work but you could end up with other problems. Note: This works regardless of which column is taller.

```css
.leftMenu {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #C0C0C0; /* C0C0C0 is used for demonstration
                                ideally this should be same as the
                                border color used in the next style */
}
.mainBox {
  border-left: 200px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.mainWrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #F8F8F8; /* this should be set to the color that displays
                                behind mainBox; its best to set it here in case
                                the left column becomes taller than main column */
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="leftMenu">left</div>
  <div class="mainBox">
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main<br>
    main
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using faux columns, you need to set background image to .mainWrapper.

Set .mainBox background to transparent and make .mainWrapper background as 200px gray at left side and all other width to white.