# Fit div height to content height IE<=7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height, html

I need to fit the height of my right bar to the height of its parent div. The parent's div height depends on other div content. I read this thread [4793540](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793201/major-problem-with-100-height-div/4793540#4793540) and found it useful for firefox and IE>=8 but older versions of IE make my bar dissapear. Can you help me whith this?

HTML

```
<div id="body">
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="trick"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    width:960px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: relative;
}
#bar {
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 870px;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#body, #bar {
    min-height: 250px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 250px;
}
#content {
    width:850px;
    float:left;
}
#trick {
    width:960px;
    height:20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

The site online is http://jazg.net/naiset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left` on `#content`.

It makes no difference in other browsers but fixes IE7.

Comment: wow! that was the kind of answer i was looking for. Thank you so much